# Is there a way to bind an html template file to directive @input?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

What I mean is that I have already a directive in angular 2 that one of its input is string or html string like that:

```
<div [my-directive]="objectString">some text</div>
<div [my-directive]="'my text string'">some text</div>
<div [my-directive]="'<div style=\'color:red\'>my html text string</div>'">some text</div>
```

All of this option will work for me.

But what if I wanna also support something like this:

```
<div [my-directive]="myhtmlfile.html">some text</div>
```

Can I do that? How it will compile into html string?

Comment: Are you trying to pass a url to an html file? ie,m make a get request to `myhtmlfile.html` then insert it ?

Comment: its just html file, something like ng-include does, but I don't wanna use it in my component as @input

Comment: where do you get the html file from?

Comment: its in the file system, I guess the same '<div style=\'color:red\'>my html text string</div>' innerhtml can be in any file, since the html can be much bigger than just a simple line

Comment: so then you'll be making a get request to get the file if you intend to serve your application from a server.

Comment: yes I suppose. Would it be wise to use ng-include ?